# What does "Position: relative" do without top, right, left, bottom?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm learning and studying the HTML/CSS codes of some of the most popular websites, and I just found that in most of them there is the "position:relative" property without the usual top, left, right, bottom properties.

Does this affect the page flow in some way, or it acts like the static property?

[image: Example]

Comment: Heres a nice article to get your head around the kinds of `position`ing that can be done in CSS. https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/ it should help you to understand why it is used in some places without `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom`

Comment: Most of the times, a parent with `position: relative` with no top/left/right/bottom has to do with the children. For instance, `absolute` positioning is relative to the closest parent that has positioned position (absolute or relative), or, if none, relative to the `body`. So, the main purpose is to say that children's position is relative to their parent.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: `position: relative` becomes a positioned element:

- This would mainly affect only it's child elements, with `position: absolute` relative to this element now, not the HTML. (Thanks Michael_B)
- `width: xx%` is also relative to this parent element if there is not fixed widths along the hierarchy.
- `z-index` now works with this element.

Comment: It can be the bounding box for all absolutely positioned descendants, not just the children. And it wouldn't otherwise be relative to the `body` element. It would look to the *initial containing block* (i.e., `html`). And `z-index` can work on non-positioned elements as well (as of CSS3).

Comment: And if there isn't any child with the absolute property, just the parent with the relative position, does this relative parent still having any difference with the static property?

Comment: @David Santiago Niño: There is more than one bullet point in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you define **absolute** position for a element. The position it will base on the closest **relative** parent. If there's no **relative** parent, the position will base on the window page.